# ¿Como declarar arrays en python?

Tags: python

Me encuentro aprendiendo python y quisiera sumar 2 arrays (a) y (b) y guardar el resultado en un tercer array (c), mi pregunta es como hacerlo, es decir si lo declaro de la siguente forma (c) me va a dar un error en el ciclo

```
import array as ar

a = ar.array("i", [27,23,24])
b = ar.array("i", [2,4,6])
c = ar.array("i", [])
```

Pero si lo declaro de esta manera no tengo ningun error

```
import array as ar

a = ar.array("i", [27,23,24])
b = ar.array("i", [2,4,6])
c = ar.array("i", [0,0,0])

for i in range(3):
    if a[i] < c[i]:
        c[i] = b[i]
    else:
        c[i] = a[i]

print([c]))
```

Personalmente no creo que esta sea la manera correcta de hacerlo y quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de declarar un array, criticas constructivas son bienvenidas, de antemano gracias por sus consejos y comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con:

```
c = ar.array("i", [])
```

estás declarando un array vacío, por lo que `if a[i] < c[i]:` va a fallar por que no existe ningún elemento en `c` que pueda accederse mediante el índice `i`. Pero esto entiendo es un error de lógica, y por el código siguiente, entiendo que en realidad estás queriendo hacer `if a[i] < b[i]`.

El otro tema son las asignaciones a `c[i]`, nuevamente el array está vacío, no puedes asignar de esta forma un nuevo elemento (con un diccionario si podrías), con los arrays vacíos, deberías agregar elementos mediante el método `append()`. Finalmente el código quedaría algo así:

```
import array as ar

a = ar.array("i", [27,23,24])
b = ar.array("i", [2,4,6])
c = ar.array("i", [])


for i in range(3):
    if a[i] < b[i]:
        c.append(b[i])
    else:
        c.append(a[i])

print(c)
```